# json.dumps(): escaping forward slashes

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, serialization, escaping

Since forward slashes can only occur in strings inside a JSON serialized object and are not escaped (in the default settings), using

```
json.dump(some_dict).replace('/', r'\/')
```

reliably works, but it looks hacky.

I know that forward slashes **don't have to be** escaped, but you **may** escape them, and for my usecase I'd like to have them escaped.

Is there a way to to let the JSONEncoder escape forward slashes without manually escaping them?

Comment: Why do you need to escape them?  What use case requires escaping?  Any reasonable JSON decoder should be able to handle unescaped forward slashes.

Comment: escaping forward slashes is not required in json, so there's no reason to expect a json encoder to support escaping slashes (or any other arbitrary character).

Comment: `dumps('</script>') == '"</script>"'`. I have not encountered any problems with that , but I would sleep better if `dumps('</script>') == '"<\\/script>"'`. :-) I would not call the forward slash an "arbitrary character". It's one of the six ASCII characters which have an escape code though you don't have to escape them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Only escape forward slashes when encode_html_chars=True**

Check out this-
https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/pull/114

The JSON spec says forward slashes shall be escaped implicitly.

Here is a solution to do it in JSONEncoder itself. Its just that you create an ESCAPE DICTIONARY and do computation before hand and do the encoding later.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/dc33addea2da464ca07e869cb11832e1ae82da9d/lib/django/django/utils/simplejson/encoder.py

Hope it helps.

-

Adding to the above solution, there is another reason to escape the characters. As **kay** said, it gives us some extra sleep. It prevents the  attack. So the solution above takes care of all issues.

```
ESCAPE_DCT = {
    # escape all forward slashes to prevent </script> attack
    '/': '\\/',
    '\\': '\\\\',
    '"': '\\"',
    '\b': '\\b',
    '\f': '\\f',
    '\n': '\\n',
    '\r': '\\r',
    '\t': '\\t',
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll use UltraJSON.

Comment: My pleasure Kay. Can my answer be marked as solution if it helped you?

Answer (score 5):

Use `escape_forward_slashes` as per ujson doc,

**escape_forward_slashes**
Controls whether forward slashes (/) are escaped. Default is True:

```
>>> ujson.dumps("http://esn.me")
'"http:\/\/esn.me"'
>>> ujson.dumps("http://esn.me", escape_forward_slashes=False)
'"http://esn.me"'
```

See [here](https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson/blob/main/README.md#escape_forward_slashes).