# Why is Flask checking `'\\/' in json.dumps('/')` in its json module?

Tags: python, flask

[The source for the `flask.json` module contains the following line.](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/json.py#L30)  What does `'\\/'` mean, and why is Flask checking this?

```
_slash_escape = '\\/' not in _json.dumps('/')
```

Comment: I am almost positive it is testing that json.dumps returns the forward-slash '/' escaped as '\/'. It also may be testing that encode_html_chars = True. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27129934/5041537

Comment: Could you link to the code in question?

Comment: What version of Flask is this from? I searched their git repo for this string and they now appear to set `json_available = True` in their \_\_init__ for "backwards compatibility", so I think this test is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flask is using this to test if the JSON library it's using escapes slashes when it doesn't have to.  If the library does, then `json.dump('/')` will produce `'"\\/"'` (equivalent to the raw string `r'"\/"'`, see [here for an explanation on escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)).

Flask can choose one of multiple JSON libraries, and some libraries/versions escape forward slashes while others don't.  [Flask includes a comment explaining this.](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/json.py#L28-L30)

If the library does escape slashes, [Flask will undo this when it dumps the JSON](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/json.py#L191-L192), for consistency between libraries.

```
# figure out if simplejson escapes slashes.  This behavior was changed
# from one version to another without reason.
_slash_escape = '\\/' not in _json.dumps('/')
...
def htmlsafe_dumps(obj, **kwargs):
    ...
    if not _slash_escape:
        rv = rv.replace('\\/', '/')
    ...
```

[Flask still escapes unsafe HTML characters](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/0.10.1/flask/json.py#L187-L190) when rendering the JSON in HTML, so the potentially unsafe string `"</script>"` becomes `"\\u003c/script\\u003e"` which is safe.

Answer (score 5):

Backslash (`\`) is the escape character. In several programming languages, it means to treat the next character as a literal whatever, instead of letting it perform its normal function (example: put a literal quote instead of treating it as an end quote).

Two backslashes (`\\`) means a literal backslash. As in, don't perform the escaping function.

So an escaped slash in JSON is `\/`, but to detect that Python has to use `\\/` or else *it* will treat the backslash as an escape.

As an aside, this is why Python offers so-called ["raw string literals"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l) prefixed by `r''`, so that you don't have to write `\\` to get a literal backslash.

Credit to [davidism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400617/davidism) for discovering the specific reason Flask does this before I could. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31883568/2588818) explaining that in more detail.

Comment: What is the meaning behind testing this?

Comment: @KyleShrader It's a way to test if the string of JSON contains an escaped forward slash (`\/`), a literal backslash followed by a forward slash. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped