# how to remove a back slash from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to create a json file like this:

```
{"946705035":4,"946706692":4 ...}
```

I am taking a column that only contains Unix Timestamp and group them.

```
result = data['Last_Modified_Date_unixtimestamp_no_time'].value_counts()

In [21]: result.head()
Out[21]: 
1508284800    131
1508716800    106
1508371200    101
1508457600     99
1508630400     96
Name: Last_Modified_Date_unixtimestamp_no_time, dtype: int64
```

transform to a dict

```
result = result.to_dict()
result
'''
{1507161600: 1,
 1507852800: 1,
 1508198400: 64,
 1508284800: 131,
 ...
 1535155200: 1,
 1535241600: 1}
'''

import json
result = json.dumps(result)

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(result, fp, indent=4)
```

result 
[image]
this is the data structure that I expected

```
{"946705035":4,"946706692":4}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to Pretty-Print JSON Data to a File using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170288/need-to-pretty-print-json-data-to-a-file-using-python)

Comment: Does this seem like a suitable solution? [Json dumps escaping forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129681/json-dumps-escaping-forward-slashes)

Comment: I see you are working with pandas dataframe. In that case, if you want to send your df as a response, instead of converting it to json, consider converting it to dict and then encoding and sending dict to json. It works well. and that is the standard way to do it. Refer to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73448710/4800690

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're dumping the JSON twice, which causes quotes to be escaped on the second dump. (After the first `json.dumps` the result is only a string, so you're just dumping a string instead of a dict again)

```
import json
# result = json.dumps(result)

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(result, fp, indent=4)
```

Or remove the second dump:

```
import json
result = json.dumps(result)

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    # json.dump(result, fp, indent=4)
    print(result, file=fp)
```

Comment: Is there a simple test for `result`'s type?  This way, one could write `if type(result) is <json string>: fp.write(result) ... else: json.dump(result,fp)`

Comment: @blong `type(result) is str`, but better yet, keep track of your code and pay attention to *where* JSON is dumped. Only do it once, as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
data_json=df.to_json(orient='records')
parsed=json.loads(data_json)

with open('my_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(parsed, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about how this solves the question

Answer (score 0):

First convert the dataframe to dict

```py
response = df.to_dict(orient="records")
```

And then encode the response to json

```py
json_compatible_data = jsonable_encoder(response)
```

This should work well.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to solve the above problem is to play with `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()`.

```
import json
result = json.dumps(result)

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.loads(result, fp)
```

Comment: Yes. You can try.

Comment: The second argument to [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) makes no sense - it accepts only one positional argument.