# How to correct improper json containing extraneous quote marks when returned by ocr engine?

Tags: python, json, regex, ocr

Our ocr engine returns results as json data:
`{"WordText":"\"*EET","Left":88.0,"Top":153.0,"Height":7.0,"Width":21.0}`

Notice that the value for "WordText" contains a double quote mark after the backslash. When I process this with json.dumps it get an "Expecting delimiter" error.  The OCR engine is creating large numbers of these types of errors when it encounters a double quote mark in the text. There does not seem to be any way to modify the output of the OCR, so I need to write post processing code to correct these errors.

I would be happy to eliminate any double quote that is not directly after a colon, or before a comma but have no idea how to do it efficiently in python or regular expressions.

Anyone have a suggestion, or tool that would clean up this type of json issue?

Comment: Do you have more examples or it's always `":"\"`?

Comment: Here are more examples, but it is random:  {"WordText":""4512","Left":1.0,"Top":94.0,"Height":7.0,"Width":24.0}            {"WordText":"IV"L","Left":98.0,"Top":135.0,"Height":6.0,"Width":13.0}

Comment: One final detail....  There is another key "LineText" that usually also contains the same error.  Primarily because "WordText" is simply "LineText" broken down by word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this of any help for the extra escaping...

[Dump to JSON adds additional double quotes and escaping of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242262/dump-to-json-adds-additional-double-quotes-and-escaping-of-quotes)

This may not be perfect (I feel it's kind of rough using two regex patterns) but for the given JSON of...

```
{"WordText":"\"*EET", "Left":88.0,"Top":153.0,"Height":7.0,"Width":21.0},
{"WordText":""4512","Left":1.0,"Top":94.0,"Height":7.0,"Width":24.0},
{"WordText":"IV"L","Left":98.0,"Top":135.0,"Height":6.0,"Width":13.0}
```

This code...

```
import pandas as pd
import re

pattern1 = re.compile(r'(?i)(\"\"|\"\\\")') # replace with: "
pattern2 = re.compile(r'(?i)(\w)(\")(\w)') # replace with: \1\3

data = '''
[{"WordText":"\"*EET", "Left":88.0,"Top":153.0,"Height":7.0,"Width":21.0},
{"WordText":""4512","Left":1.0,"Top":94.0,"Height":7.0,"Width":24.0},
{"WordText":"IV"L","Left":98.0,"Top":135.0,"Height":6.0,"Width":13.0}]
'''

data = pattern1.sub(r'"', data)
data = pattern2.sub(r'\1\3', data)

#load it into a pandas dataframe just to prove it is valid
df = pd.read_json(data)

print(df)
```

Outputs...

```
  WordText  Left  Top  Height  Width
0     *EET    88  153       7     21
1     4512     1   94       7     24
2      IVL    98  135       6     13
```

Maybe look at that extra escaping link at the start of the answer and see if there is a problem there.  This may also be useful...

[how to remove a back slash from a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050108/how-to-remove-a-back-slash-from-a-json-file)

**

### UPDATE:

**

Here is new code with an example of corrupted JSON being fixed by two regex patterns.  I don't have your JSON but it shows the regex should help for the corruption described so far.  I've commented the code to help explain it

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# compile a pattern to match "\"text" OR ""text" which needs replacing with a single doublequote
pattern1 = re.compile(r'(?i)(\"\"|\"\\\")')

# compile a second pattern to match "te"xt" which needs to be replacing with nothing/blank/just remove
pattern2 = re.compile(r'(?i)\b(\")\b')

# if this was the input (good_data) it would work without any clean up
good_data = '''
{"Sub_ID":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ],
        "Name":["Erik", "Daniel", "Michael", "Sven",
                "Gary", "Carol","Lisa", "Elisabeth" ],
        "Salary":["723.3", "515.2", "621", "731", 
                  "844.15","558", "642.8", "732.5" ],
        "StartDate":[ "1/1/2011", "7/23/2013", "12/15/2011",
                     "6/11/2013", "3/27/2011","5/21/2012", 
                     "7/30/2013", "6/17/2014"],
        "Department":[ "IT", "Management", "IT", "HR", 
                      "Finance", "IT", "Management", "IT"],
        "Sex":[ "M", "M", "M", 
              "M", "M", "F", "F", "F"]}
'''

# copied good_data and corrupted it with "\"Erik", ""Gary", and "Mana"gement"
bad_data = '''
{"Sub_ID":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8" ],
        "Name":["\"Erik", "Daniel", "Michael", "Sven",
                ""Gary", "Carol","Lisa", "Elisabeth" ],
        "Salary":["723.3", "515.2", "621", "731", 
                  "844.15","558", "642.8", "732.5" ],
        "StartDate":[ "1/1/2011", "7/23/2013", "12/15/2011",
                     "6/11/2013", "3/27/2011","5/21/2012", 
                     "7/30/2013", "6/17/2014"],
        "Department":[ "IT", "Management", "IT", "HR", 
                      "Finance", "IT", "Mana"gement", "IT"],
        "Sex":[ "M", "M", "M", 
              "M", "M", "F", "F", "F"]}
'''

# run the bad_data through the find and replace for the two patterns
# first one finds such mistakes as "\"text" OR ""text" and replaces with a single doublequote
bad_data = pattern1.sub(r'"', bad_data)

# second pattern finds a doublequote on its own in the middle of a word like "te"xt" and removes it
bad_data = pattern2.sub(r'', bad_data)

# read the fixed bad_data into a pandas dataframe to check it's valid
df = pd.read_json(bad_data)

# print out the df
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
   Sub_ID       Name  Salary   StartDate  Department Sex
0       1       Erik  723.30    1/1/2011          IT   M
1       2     Daniel  515.20   7/23/2013  Management   M
2       3    Michael  621.00  12/15/2011          IT   M
3       4       Sven  731.00   6/11/2013          HR   M
4       5       Gary  844.15   3/27/2011     Finance   M
5       6      Carol  558.00   5/21/2012          IT   F
6       7       Lisa  642.80   7/30/2013  Management   F
7       8  Elisabeth  732.50   6/17/2014          IT   F
```

If you comment out the regex replaces lines of...

```
bad_data = pattern1.sub(r'"', bad_data)
bad_data = pattern2.sub(r'', bad_data)
```

...and get pandas to read the JSON it errors with...

```
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)
```

...which is expected.

Comment: I like the direction you are heading.  What does replacing the "  -> '\1\3'  accomplish?   It occurs to me we could use three regex patterns to handle the three invalid use cases:  The value starts with two double quotes,  The value ends with two double quotes, or the value contains a quote between two characters.   Your pattern2 handles the use case three.  Could we just define two patterns to handle the starts with and ends with double quote use case?

Comment: Could we use (r'(?i)(WordText":""/w+",)   and replace it with WordText":"/w+",      So it would recognize that there were two quotes to start and replace that with a single? 
  Sorry, I have been studying Regex but still do not understand how it works in some of these more complex situations!

Comment: The `replace with:` are just comments on what to replace the found section with in lines 13 and 14.  The `""` is already found in `pattern1` where `\"\"` in `(?i)(\"\"|\"\\\")` means find two double-quotes together (i.e., "").  The rest of `pattern1`, after the `|` that is `\"\\\"` means 'actually find "\" in the string'   If there is another double-quote section to find and replace I'd suggest updating the question with a chunk of JSON that has all the problems.

Comment: What I'm saying above is that you have three patterns covered in the two patterns because you have an OR in the first pattern for either `""` or `"\"`

Comment: The data is coming from an OCR program, so there are an unlimited number of cases where the OCR might find a random double quote in the text being OCR'd.   So I need to handle any situation that might contain more than a leading and trailing double quote.   Here is another example - {"LineText":"101 "APORT","Words":[{"WordText":"101","Left":49.0,"Top":108.0,"Height":6.0,"Width":14.0},{"WORDTEXT":"APORT","Left":66.0,"Top":108.0,"Height":6.0,"Width":40.0}

Comment: I do not understand why the line uses "\1\3 " -  data = pattern2.sub(r'\1\3', data)

Comment: it was because the previous regex matched the letter before and after the doublequote in the middle of the word and the find and replace has to be them back.  Those letters were captured into groups 1 and 3 so that's \1\3.  However, the new code has different regex.  Hope the update helps.